# MSSQL исключить преобразование строки в INT

Tags: sql-server, типы-данных, преобразование

Необходимо где id совпадают - вывести id, где нет - вывести null.
Все ломает преобразование строки 't' в INT. Можно ли как-то поймать ошибку и если она возникает - пропустить это поле?

"Ошибка преобразования значения varchar "t" в тип данных int."

```
CREATE TABLE #testTbl(
   id INT
);
INSERT INTO #testTbl
VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #strTbl;
CREATE TABLE #strTbl(
   id VARCHAR(255)
);
INSERT INTO #strTbl
VALUES (1), (2), ('t'), (5);

SELECT *
FROM #testTbl AS ttest
LEFT JOIN #strTbl AS tstr
 ON ttest.id = CAST(tstr.id AS INT)
```

Comment: [TRY_CAST](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql)

Comment: почему вы строку к целому приводите, а не наоборот?

Comment: На самом деле зависит от версии SQL server